# Given verticies find the area of the triangle formed

Tags: vectors, triangles, area, cross-product

When I looked at this problem I didn't think it seemed all that hard until I actually tried it. The problem is this:

Given the rectangular vertices $O(0, 0, 0), P(-1, 2, -3), Q(-2, 3, -4), R(0, 0, 1)$, find the area of the triangle formed.

So since I am given 4 points, I know this is a parallelepiped of some sort. The formula for the Area of a parallelogram is $A = | b \times c |$ so that means the Area of the triangle would be $A = |b \times c| / 2$ since triangle is one-half base(height).

So I know I need vectors in order to use these formulas so I get these vectors by subtracting two points. So $\overrightarrow{OP} = \langle -1-0, 2-0, -3-0 \rangle = \langle -1, 2, -3\rangle$. Likewise, $\overrightarrow{OQ} = \langle -2, 3, -4 \rangle$ and $\overrightarrow{OR} = \langle 0, 0, 1 \rangle$

Let's set $\mathbf{b} = \overrightarrow{OQ}$ and $\mathbf{c} = \overrightarrow{OR}$. Then we must find $|\mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{c}|$ and then times that by half to get the area of the triangle.

$\langle -2, 3, -4 \rangle \times \langle 0, 0, 1 \rangle = (3-0)i-(-2-0)j+(0-0)k = 3i+2j$

$|3i+2j|/2 = \sqrt{9+4}/2 = \sqrt{13}/2$

I did the cross product by hand and after multiplying by 1/2 I got the answer to be $\sqrt{13}/2$ but when I look at the answer key, the answer the professor wrote was $\sqrt{14}/2$.

I am wondering why I am 1 digit off in that upper radical. Can anyone help explain why I am getting 1 off, or maybe there is a mistake on the answer sheet? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe if you show us what did you do by hand we may be able to help you. There is a possibility that you made a mistake in the cross product calculation.

Comment: Did the problem asked to find the area of the triangle? Why is there 4 points? Did the problem originally ask to find the volume of the parallelpiped formed by the four vertices?

Comment: @JoaquinLiniado I added it to the best of my ability. I'm not sure how to show the full $i, j, k$ matrix which is how I do it.

Comment: @MathNewbie This is part a) of the question. There is, in fact, another part of the problem later that asks to find the volume of the parallelepiped formed.

Comment: These four points are definitely not coplanar. So using another set of three points, I find that the area of the triangle is not $\sqrt{14}/2$. The question is which three coordinates or perhaps an error on the answer key?

Comment: I tried a multiple combination of coordinates and the closest I got was $\sqrt{13}/2$ so I am leaning towards an error on the answer key.

Comment: There's a huge possibility that is the case.

Comment: Check triangle PQR, that should give you $\sqrt{14}/2$. It would be beneficial if it stated which three points, but now you know.

Comment: So am I not supposed to use point $O$?

Comment: Three points in the plane makes a triangle. I tried 4 combinations and this specific combination gave me $\sqrt{14}/2$. I have tried $OPQ$ and that didn't yield $\sqrt{14}/2$ or any other ones. It just doesn't make sense for the professor to not specify which triangle (s)he was interested in finding the area of.

Comment: Okay, cool. I'm just trying to figure out since there are multiple combinations which one is right on a test without seeing an answer key.

Comment: Is it because $O$ is the origin that I should have used the other points?

Comment: In my opinion, this had nothing to do with $O$ being an origin. But was a poorly worded question if your professor expects you to get one of the four correctly without specifying which specific triangle.

Comment: Okay gotcha. Yeah, the professor did not specify which triangle. She literally gave us the 4 points and said to find the area of the triangle formed.